# UIModelPrestationFormSheet keyboard hides the textfield

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios5

UIModelPrestationFormSheet in that i've 2textfields in that i want to type somthing in the 2nd textfield but textfield hides behinds the keyboard-->https://i.stack.imgur.com/Chdv3.png
while i tap the 2nd textfield the keyboard gets hided>>>https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RR0v.png

[image: 2Textfield in formsheet in that 2nd textfield gets hided by keyboard]

[image: while i tap the 2nd textfield the keyboard gets hided]

Comment: pleas, provide more information, so we can help you.

Comment: not able to add image basheer

Comment: use the keyboardNotifications and change the frame of the textfield when the keyboard comes up..

Comment: Yes Divya but i'm working on orientation also so i've tried a lot did you have some other idea in keyboardnotification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this tutorial from Apple documentations 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

 Look for

> Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard